# Wordpress 4.9.8 doesn't save if content has style="

Tags: save-post, 500-internal-error, draft, customization

Wordpress 4.9.8 when I save a draft/publish return me an error:

```
    Gone

The requested resource
/wp-admin/post.php
is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource.
```

I found that the problem is because my text has "  style="bla bla bla" ". If I remove style= it works.
I tried disabling all plugins, change to default theme, create a new installation, change PHP version from 5.6 to 7, 7.1, 7.2 : doesn't change.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot replicate this error, so it must have something to do with your particular setup.

Comment: This sounds like something mod_security or some kind of firewall might do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same issue recently.

Inline styles, as well as `<img>` tags, would cause the `410 Gone` status and error message (`The requested resource /wp-admin/post.php is no longer available on this server and there is no forwarding address. Please remove all references to this resource.` upon previewing or publishing the post.

The problem was due to the hosting provider doing some maintenance on `mod_security` in cPanel.

I found out when I asked them for the Apache logs so that I could look into it more.

Contact your hosting provider to get this fixed.

Comment: Hi Francensco, my provider too (www.register.it). Disabling and re-enabling mod_security, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
as @milo suggests, I found solution disabling mod_security under cPanel. So I ask to my hoster (register.it) if there was some problem. They confirm me that servers are under updating security stuff and to disable and then re-able mod_security in CPanel. After that, post.php works properly.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

in general it's not a good idea to insert inline styles.

try with a CSS class and add your custom CSS to your theme.

Comment: That's always true, but when clients copy/paste from Word or other stuff, I cannot always clear HTML...